# crash on zooming on core plot graph in iOS app

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using core plot library in my app to draw a xy grapg.I have given setAllowPinchScaling bool yes and zooming actions working fine.But when user do continuous zooming app crashes.So I need to set minimum and maximum zoom level and disable zooming after this particular values(To avoid crash).Please tell me how to do this in core plot ?

My code is

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

CPTTheme *theme             = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];
```

// hostingView.collapsesLayers   = NO; // Setting to YES reduces GPU memory usage, but can slow drawing/scrolling
    hostingView.hostedGraph     = graph;

```
// **-- Disabling pinch zoom ability of graph
[hostingView setAllowPinchScaling:YES];


// **-- Padding
graph.paddingLeft           = 0.0;
graph.paddingTop            = 0.0;
graph.paddingRight          = 0.0;
graph.paddingBottom         = 0.0;


// **--  Seting up plot space ----
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace           = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction     = YES;
```

This is starting point and after this I will give x and y ranges.

Comment: It would be helpful to add relevant code you already have tried to your question. This can help people in answering your question.

Comment: @SidneyGijzen,  this is how I draw graph

Comment: Where is it crashing? What error messages do you get? Can you post the stack trace?